# How to convert element in string array x[i] to a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, swt

Looking at the code snippet below, the method `maxFont.LabelFont(Label tmp, String tmp2)`only accepts string input, not an element in a string array. When I try to use `x[i].toString()`, the string gets displayed as `Label{xxxx}` instead of just `xxxx`.

```
// for each column, prompt user to Insert data for that category
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    maxFont.textFont(y[i]);

    // Add label x[i] prompting for category value
    x[i].setParent(mUpdate);
    maxFont.labelFont(x[i],x[i].toString());
    // Add text field tmp2 to input the new data
    y[i].setParent(mUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the minimum compilable code necessary to reproduce the issue.  As it stands there are far too many questions about what your code is doing to be able to help.

Comment: For instance the most important: What is x?

Comment: Given the `swt` tag, and the method signature, it seems pretty clear to me that `x` is an `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label`.

Comment: But given [swt] tag, I would expect to see `x[i].setParent(mUpdate);`. Even if technically possible, this is *never* used!

Answer (score 0):

Since `toString()` in this case always returns `Label(xxxx)` you can use substrings or split to extract `xxxx`.

Here's a concise way to do it with split:

```
Label(xxxx).split( "[\\\\(\\\\)]")[1]
```

So in your code you'd use

```
maxFont.labelFont(x[i],x[i].split( "[\\\\(\\\\)]")[1]);
```

Note that the double backslashes are needed, and so are the brackets `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `String.valueOf`?

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is indeed an SWT [`Label`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Label.html), then you want:

```
x[i].getText()
```

instead of

```
x[i].toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If x is your object - override toString() or add your private method.

Else - may be you can cast x to its type and to use appropeiated property.